# setInterval not working when declared as global

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have 3 setInterval functions declared globally, 2 of them are working the other doesn't work no matter what I do. I am using a separate function to clear the intervals (function ClearintervalTime()), which is called in stopGame()

```
var clearIntervalvariable0, clearIntervalvariable1, clearGameInterval1=null;

function gameDuration() {
    counter = 90;
    clearGameInterval1 = setInterval(gameDurationCounter, 1000);

    function gameDurationCounter() {
        counter--;
        document.getElementById('timer').innerText = 'Time remaining:' + counter;
        speed();
        if (counter == 0) {
            stopGame();
            // clearInterval(clearGameInterval1);
            console.log('game was stopped');
        };
    };
};

function ClearintervalTime() {
    clearInterval(clearGameInterval1);
    clearInterval(clearIntervalvariable0);
    clearInterval(clearIntervalvariable1);

};
function stopGame() {
    bubbles.length = 0;
    noLoop();
    ClearintervalTime();
};
```

This code doesn't work no matter what i do, the only to make it work is if i declare the clearGameInterval1 locally in gameDuration() and then close it in the closure function gameDurationCounter() with the commentated line.
I have a stop game button, and i want to close the interval not only when the counter reaches 0 but on buttonclick aswell.
If i leave the code as it's listed above the counter will not even start, if I comment out the clearInterval(clearGameInterval1); in the ClearintervalTime(), the counter will start but I'm unable to stop/clear it... I'm going out of my mind trying to solve this. There are no other variables or functions with the same name, and I've tried to getting gameDurationCounter() outside (not in a closure) same effect. Can someone please tell me what's happening, what is going wrong?

Comment: And how is `gameDuration` called? If you keep calling that function without clearing the interval first, it keeps adding a new interval to the global, and the handler for the old interval is lost, and it can no longer be cleared.

Comment: Do you have several games running at the same time, or can only one game run at the time? This question would be much clearer if you would provide a snippet that can be run and which reproduces the issue.

Comment: set clearGameInterval1 to 0 and check

Comment: gameDuration is called when you click the start button, that has this function attached onclick:
function startGame(bubbleSpawnInterval) {
    if (!bubbleSpawnInterval) {
        alert('Please select a difficulty!');
    } else {
        initializingVariavles();
        gameDuration();
        loop();
        randomTimers(bubbleSpawnInterval);
        difficultyLevel(bubbleSpawnInterval);
    };
}

Answer (score 1):

After spending more than 2 days on this issue, i finally found the error..and it was all me :(. I was starting the game, and the game counter 
gameDuration() in the  startGame();

```
function startGame(bubbleSpawnInterval) {
if (!bubbleSpawnInterval) {
    alert('Please select a difficulty!');
} else {
    initializingVariavles();
    loop();
    gameDuration();
    randomTimers(bubbleSpawnInterval);
    difficultyLevel(bubbleSpawnInterval);

};
```

};
In  difficultyLevel(bubbleSpawnInterval) i was clearing all 3 intervals, but i was setting the other 2 (that were working) in the same function, while the counter interval was still cleared... I just had to place the gameDuration() function after the difficultyLevel(bubbleSpawnInterval) to make it work.

```
function startGame(bubbleSpawnInterval) {
    if (!bubbleSpawnInterval) {
        alert('Please select a difficulty!');
    } else {
        initializingVariavles();
        loop();
        randomTimers(bubbleSpawnInterval);
        difficultyLevel(bubbleSpawnInterval);
        gameDuration();
    };
};
```